# EasyAdmin shows user as "unnamed" even if logged

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have implemented Symfony authentication and restrict access to easyadmin page.
If I log in, the Symfony's debug toolbar shows:

`Authenticated: Yes
Logged in as: my@email...`

But on the top right corner in EasyAdmin, There is a user snippet showing
`Logged in as: Unnamed`

How to set a name, so the EasyAdmin user snippet shows the logged user's name?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this configuration.
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/basic-configuration.html

## config/packages/easy_admin.yaml

user:

```
    # this method/property must return the string representation of the user
    # (Symfony will look for getFullName(), isFullName(), ..., and 'fullName' property)

    name_property_path: 'fullName'
```

If you want to show here the user's email address, you must change the 'fullName' to the property name, which is in your User entity (for example 'email')

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/basic-configuration.html